# Failed to prevent screenshot for unity app

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, screenshot

I want to prevent screenshot on my unity app.

So, I applied my code refering following url.
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/SurfaceView#setSecure(boolean)

It was worked in general screenshot on any android devices and screencapture app, except google assistant.

here's some steps to reproduce the issue.

1. Export unity sample app for Android Studio.
2. apply following codes in onCreate function (UnityPlayerActivity.java).

   ```
   View v = this.getWindow().getDecorView();
   ViewGroup vg = (ViewGroup) v;
   for( int i=0; i< vg.getChildCount(); i++)
   {
      if ( vg.getChildAt(i) instanceof SurfaceView)
      {
         ((SurfaceView) vg.getChildAt(i)).setSecure(true);
      }
   }
   ```
3. launch sample app.

I also refered following url for my app to prevent screenshot through google assistant.
https://developer.android.com/training/articles/assistant#excluding_views

According to this article, google assistant excepts current view if secure flag sets true.

So I found all SurfaceView child and set secure flag to true.

As I wrote, it was worked in general screenshot on any android devices and screencapture app, except google assistant.

I also changed ViewGroup object to unity object(mUnityPlayer), but result was same.

What am I missed here?

Answer (score 0):

**I want to prevent screenshot on my unity app.**
Have a look[image]
https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/PlayerSettings-protectGraphicsMemory.html

Comment: Thanks, phantasm!
That option requires a device that supports the EGL_PROTECTED_CONTENT_EXT extension (docs) and it's not work for my Pixel2 device.
I think I need to find another way...;)